# Saving CImage gives Error: identifier "ImageFormatJPEG" is undefined

Tags: image, visual-studio-2012, save, jpeg, gdi+

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
I'm trying to save a CImage as a jpg using the following:

```
theImage.Save(filePathAndName, Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG);
```

as shown at [link to Microsoft example using CImage::Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06f3fhw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, Visual Studio gives the error:

```
Error: identifier "ImageFormatJPEG" is undefined
```

Why am I getting this error?

Note, I have included the following:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
```

Also, I looked into gdiplus.h and saw the following line:

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
```

enclosing, among others, `#include "GdiplusImaging.h"`.  GdiplusImaging.h also uses

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
```

to enclose, among others, the

```
DEFINE_GUID(ImageFormatJPEG, 0xb96b3cae,0x0728,0x11d3,0x9d,0x7b,0x00,0x00,0xf8,0x1e,0xf3,0x2e);
```

I think this might be causing the problem, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to directly specify the image format using

```
Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG
```

as the second argument for the save function.

However, as specified at [Microsoft's CImage::Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06f3fhw.aspx)

> If the guidFileType parameter is not included, the file name's file extension will be used to determine the image format.

Thus, I did the following:

```
char *filePathAndName = "C:\\Projects\\AcesHyAcceptanceTestScreenShot2.jpg";
theImage.Save(filePathAndName);
```

to save the CImage as a jpeg.

If someone knows the fix to be able to use `Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG` please post the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Including "[atlimage.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx)" should work for you.